# Eclipse Plugin only working on my machine

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, development-environment, versions

I wrote a Eclipse plugin for adding hungry-deletion, and it appears to work on my machine.  However, I had a few friends try it, and it doesn't seem to load at all on their machines.  The installation process is just to copy the resulting .jar to the plugins/ subdirectory of eclipse.  I've tried re-installing eclipse on my machine and installing the plugin again, and that seems to work.  Is there a signing process or something I have to go through for my plugin to work on different machines?  If not, what could be the issue?

Comment: Do your friends get some sort of message in an error log? I believe Eclipse has a start-up error log that details these things, wish I could remember where it was... edit: log might be in `workspace/.metadata/.log` EDIT: this link has better info: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html

Comment: It doesn't look like there's an error, more just the plugin not being located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is the plugin was written in Eclipse 3.6 and not working in Eclipse 3.5 installations.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried starting eclipse w/ the `-clean` flag?

Comment: + check the Eclipse configuration at your friends' machine (in About Eclipse), make sure it is listed.

Comment: Starting with -clean didn't work.  It doesn't seem to be listed under About Eclipse - what should I do to install it?

Answer (score 0):

try to copy the plugin not to plugins directory but to dropins